# jQuery AJAX call PHP Class function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I wrote an user action analysis but I can't execute my `insert into` statement. I tried all suggestion on stack can't but figure out my mistake, I don't even get an error: it is running through without executing the statement. I have also an connection php - this works fine so the fault is not there. I would like to insert the `action` var later but at first I have to call the function. So whats wrong with my request or php function?

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var action = '';
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (e.nodeName === 'SECTION') {
      action = e.id;
      updateAction();
    }
  }, false);

  function updateAction() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../actions/userAction.php',
      data: {action: 'test'},
      success: function(){
        console.log(action);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
class userAction
{
  /* User Action */
  public function updateAction(){
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
      $db = getDB();
      $st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_analysis (action) VALUES ('bla') where userID = 1945");
      $st->execute();
      $db = null;
      $_SESSION['uid']=$uid;
      return true;
    }    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: why i can't call my php function he is not inserting in db

Comment: First of all check whether you are entering `updateAction()` in this function? if entering then check you are getting value in post or not. And also query is wrong

Comment: `INSERT` command cannot have `WHERE` clause. IF you are updating a record, use `UPDATE`

Comment: Pankaj yeah this is the fault i think i can't enter the function and getting an syntax error in the comment  here my whole code [link](http://dpaste.com/3RG83YS)

Comment: Where are you calling the PHP function `updateAction()`?

Comment: @mY777 : Try using `method:"POST"` in your ajax may this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call `updateAction()` method? I assume you don't. Then why do you expect that it will execute? You have at least 3 ways to deal with it.

**1. Make the method static and call it without instantiating a class**

If you don't have any reason to construct an object of your class then you can call your method without doing it. Just add this line of code after your class definition:

`userAction::updateAction()`

This way you call the method which handles your POST request.

**2. Instantiate your class and then call your method**

The same story as above. The difference here is to construct an object first:

```
$ua = new userAction();
$ua->updateAction();
```

**3. (the easiest) Get rid of the class and method**

As the title suggest. Remove whole code of a class and leave only the body of your method. Like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
   $db = getDB();
   $st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_analysis (action) VALUES ('bla') where userID = 1945");
   $st->execute();
   $db = null;
   $_SESSION['uid']=$uid;

   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

This should be the whole content of your file: a condition.

**BTW**
1. Your query is not valid. If you want to UPDATE a row you need to use `UPDATE` statement, not `INSERT`
2. I would suggest you call your class `UserAction` (uppercase). Just to make it standardised and more intuitive
3. Why do you mix jQuery with VanillaJS? You use jQuery and bind an event using clear JS. Make it semantic and decide if you use jQuery or not.
jQuery way:

```
var action = '';
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (e.nodeName === 'SECTION') {
    action = e.id;
    updateAction();
  }
});
```

That's all. I hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {     
  echo $_POST['action'];
}
```

`echo` the value of `$_POST['action']` inside your if loop...If not getting try to change the - type: "`POST`", to "`GET`",

Comment: try to solve the syntax error, and change the type as GET

Comment: I assume you forgot about `;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`. Try this below code:

```
UPDATE user_analysis SET action = 'bla' WHERE id = 1945
```

Comment: unfortunately no , problem is don't get any error so if i can debug it but i think it is an syntax error , the ajax call is right or ?